# How to change names of error queues and exchanges in MassTransit for RabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I tried to throw some exceptions in a simple configuration and noticed the creation of a few exchanges and one queue related to errors:

Exchanges:

- `MassTransit:Fault`
- `MassTransit:Fault--ConsoleApp1:Program-YourMessage--`

Queues:

- `ReceiveEndPointQueue_error`

How can I change or customize the naming of those above?

`Program.cs`:

```
public static class Program
{
    public class YourMessage
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyMessage
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

    public static async Task Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.OverrideDefaultBusEndpointQueueName("DefaultBusEndpointQueue");
            configuration.Message<YourMessage>(x =>
            {
                x.SetEntityName("YourMessageEntity");
            });
            configuration.Message<MyMessage>(x =>
            {
                x.SetEntityName("MyMessageEntity");
            });


            var host = configuration.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
            {
            });
            configuration.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "ReceiveEndPointQueue", ep =>
            {
                ep.Handler<YourMessage>(async context => throw new Exception("YourMessage"));
                ep.Handler<MyMessage>(async context => await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Received MyMessage: {context.Message.Number}"));
            });
        });

        await bus.StartAsync(); 
        await bus.Publish(new YourMessage{Text = "Hi"});
        await bus.Publish(new MyMessage {Number= 42});
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
        await bus.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly quoted https://gitter.im/MassTransit/MassTransit

> ```
> Ehouarn Perret
> @ehouarn-perret
> May 30 20:14
> "I am still looking for a way to change the default names of Error Exchanges / Queues when using MassTransit with RabbitMQ, can't find anything in the documentation"
>
> Chris Patterson
> @phatboyg
> May 30 20:31
> "There isnt' a way to change them, it's always queue_error"
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Given that this is the number one result on google, this is how you can change the default fault exchange names in the above question example:

```cs
public static class Program
{
    public class YourMessage
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyMessage
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

    public static async Task Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.OverrideDefaultBusEndpointQueueName("DefaultBusEndpointQueue");
            configuration.Message<YourMessage>(x =>
            {
                x.SetEntityName("YourMessageEntity");
            });
            configuration.Message<MyMessage>(x =>
            {
                x.SetEntityName("MyMessageEntity");
            });
            
            // customization of fault starts here
            configuration.Message<Fault>(x =>
            {
                x.SetEntityName("Fault");
            });

            configuration.Message<Fault<MyMessageEntity>>(x =>
            {
                x.SetEntityName("FaultMyMessageEntity");
            });
            
            configuration.Message<Fault<YourMessageEntity>>(x =>
            {
                x.SetEntityName("FaultYourMessageEntity");
            });
            // customization of fault ends here            

            var host = configuration.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
            {
            });
            configuration.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "ReceiveEndPointQueue", ep =>
            {
                ep.Handler<YourMessage>(async context => throw new Exception("YourMessage"));
                ep.Handler<MyMessage>(async context => await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Received MyMessage: {context.Message.Number}"));
            });
        });

        await bus.StartAsync(); 
        await bus.Publish(new YourMessage{Text = "Hi"});
        await bus.Publish(new MyMessage {Number= 42});
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
        await bus.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

The `_error` queue, I haven't found a way to change it but it will follow the receive endpoint name plus `_error`.

https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/topology/message

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to change error queue name, although not too elegant:

```
        Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.SendTopology.ConfigureErrorSettings = settings =>
            {
                if (settings is RabbitMqErrorSettings rabbitMqErrorSettings)
                {
                    rabbitMqErrorSettings.QueueName = "Your queue name";
                }
            };
        });
```

And it should be borne in mind that this won't change the existing topology. If a queue with the default name was created, it will remain with the same bindings.